# Combining a bar plot and a line plot in matplotlib without shifting the bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to combine a bar and a line plot, without the bar plot shifting when the line plot is added.

The following code is used to generate the barplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame([[4,30,0,3,2,2,], [5,24,0,3,1,1,], [6,34,0,4,2,1], [7,18,0,2,1,1], [8,34,0,3,3,2]], columns=['t', 'Cost', 0,1,2,3])
data[[1,2,3]].plot(kind='bar')
```

Thus, the data looks as follows
[image]

and the following plot is generated:

[image]

Next, I add the cost information using

```
data['Cost'].plot(style='o--', c='black', secondary_y=True)
```

Running it all together returns the following graph:

[image]

The issue is that the outer bars are no longer visible. I tried changing the range on the x-axis with xlim, but that did not help, it only made it worse. There is probably an easy fix for it, which I have not been able to find anywhere online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the issue, running your code:

[image: bar + line]

That said, an easy fix is to run `ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 4.5)`

Comment: Interesting, because I do have this issue. Could it be due to any of the default settings  related to plotting, because I do not get the figure you showed.

Comment: I forgot, if `ax` is not defined use `plt.gca().set_xlim(...)`